# Why might "mkdir -p" lead to a Bash permission error?

Tags: bash, permissions, mkdir

If I make a directory with `mkdir -p`, it causes problems with scripts

```bsh
$ mkdir -p test2/test2

$ cd test2/test2

$ echo '#!/bin/sh
> echo hello' > hello.sh

$ ./hello.sh
bash: ./hello.sh: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is nothing to do with `mkdir`.  You simply haven't given `hello.sh` executable permissions.  You need the following:

```
chmod +x hello.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Check your permissions

Check the permissions on your directories and the script itself. There may be a problem there, although it's unlikely.

```
ls -lad test2/test2
ls -l test2/test2/hello.sh
```

You can always use the **--mode** flag with *mkdir* if your permissions aren't being set correctly for some reason. See chmod(1) and mkdir(1) for more information.

#### Execute the file directly

You can execute the script with Bash directly, rather than relying on a shebang line or the executable bit, as long as the file is readable by the current user. For example:

```
bash test2/test2/hello.sh
```

#### Change file permissions

If you can execute the file when invoked explicitly with Bash, then you just need to make sure your file has the execute bit set. For example:

```
chmod 755 test2/test2/hello.sh
```